# How to display mirror image of camera in aframe?

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

If I'm using the front-facing camera of my laptop, I want to display the mirror image on the screen. How can I achieve this? Right now, when I raise my left hand, the image feed raises its right. I want to invert this if possible, such that the image feed also raises the left hand for example